# How to clip text label in Libgdx

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I have a `Label` with defined width and height, and I want text added to it to be clipped if it can't fit the label instead of increasing its size (height rather).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with the following [instruction](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Clipping,-with-the-use-of-scissorstack) using the `ScissorStack`. I hope this may help you!